# Override sql default value on insert using Entity Framework Core (7)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a table with a column [CreatedAtIsoUtc] that sets a Sql Server default value

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "CurrentAccountLedger",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "newsequentialid()"),
                CreatedAtIsoUtc = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()"),                    
            }

        });
```

In a raw sql server query, I can insert a record and overwrite the [CreatedAtIsoUtc] default value.

In Entity Framework, I can't seem to overwrite this value when performing an Add() operation.

Any ideas on how I could get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually in EF Core v1.1.0 you can do that by setting the property to any value **different** than the default for the type (i.e. `0` for numbers, `false` for `bool`, `null` for `string` and nullable types, `default(DateTime)` in your case). The only current limitation is that you cannot override the sql default value with `0`, `false`, `null` etc.

For instance

```
db.CurrentAccountLedger.Add(new CurrentAccountLedger { });
```

would insert a record with `CreatedAtIsoUtc` equals to the default `GETUTCDATE()`, while

```
db.CurrentAccountLedger.Add(new CurrentAccountLedger { CreatedAtIsoUtc = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1) });
```

would insert a record with the specified value.

Comment: Thanks. I originally tried this but it wasn't working for some reason. Just re-ran and it works. Not sure where I messed up.

Comment: Does it means that with EfCore null value can NOT be inserted to nullable column which has default value:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969303/ef-core-insert-null-value-to-nullable-column-that-has-default-value

Comment: @Boris Indeed (`null` for string and **nullable types**)

Answer (score 2):

You can set raw SQL defaults on your entities in your context's `OnModelCreating()` using `HasDefaultValueSql()`:

```
class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CurrentAccountLedger> CurrentAccountLedgers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CurrentAccountLedger>()
            .Property(x => x.CreatedAtIsoUtc)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");
    }
}
```