# EF Core insert null value to nullable column that has default value

Tags: entity-framework, null, nullable, default-value

I am curious about specific scenario in SQL when using EF Core.
For example there is a column that allows null and at the same time has defalut value, it is unusual situation but that is not the issue here.
Question is about technical possibility.

```
[SomeId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL DEFAULT (newsequentialid())
```

And in Application there is Entity(Code First) which has appropriate Property

```
public Guid? SomeId { get; set; }
```

The problem is how to Insert this Entity into DB so that *SomeId* would have Null value. Because even when property is Null, Database will override it with default value.

This can be done with pure sql by explicitly assigning null to column but it seems that the same can't be done with EF, or am I wrong ?

EDIT:
To elaborate more

```
public class ExampleTable
{
    [Key]
    int Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    Guid? SomeId { get; set; }
}
```

In Seed method for example:

```
var record1 = new ExampleTable
{
    FirstName = "Carson"
}
var record2 = new ExampleTable
{
    FirstName = "Carson",
    SomeId = null
}
context.ExampleTableSet.Add(record1);
context.ExampleTableSet.Add(record2);
context.SaveChanges(record);
```

record 1 and 2 are the same since *SomeId* is nullable Guid?, and in both cases after Submiting *SomeId* in database gets real value from *newsequentialid*.
Is there any way to keep *SomeId* Null in database as well.

Comment: ANSWER: This can NOT be done through EF:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668301/override-sql-default-value-on-insert-using-entity-framework-core-7/41683417#41683417

Comment: You can do this with SqlDefaultValue and still allow the type to be nullable. Like so:'modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType).Property("RowPointer").HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()")'. If you do this all you are saying is. In my persistence tier I want this behavior, but for my application this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question fully, but by modifying your declaration you can set the default value. On creation of a record, 'SomeId' will default to *NULL*

```
    public class ExampleTable
    {
        public ExampleTable()
        {
            SomeId = null;
        }

        public Guid? SomeId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I have added more info to question.

Comment: I was referring to value in database which does not stays Null.